# Ling-to-Sql issue when bind SQL to WP8 using WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, xaml, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

I have just tried to create my first `WP8 application` which would `Bind data from SQL Database`. I followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e39H8wWWXEo) tutorial but only `black page appears`.

As there is no ListBox in WP8 tools I used `LongListSelector` as following:

MainPage.xaml

```
 shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ToursDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding name}"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <phone:LongListSelector 
        x:Name="MyLongListSelectors"

        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ToursDataTemplate}"
         />
```

This is my MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using PhoneApp1.Resources;
using PhoneApp1.ToursServiceReference1;


namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }
        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToursServiceReference1.ToursService1Client serviceClient = new ToursServiceReference1.ToursService1Client();

            serviceClient.GetAllKlientsCompleted += new EventHandler<ToursServiceReference1.GetAllKlientsCompletedEventArgs>(serviceClient_GetAllKlientsCompleted);

        serviceClient.GetAllKlientsAsync();
    }
    private void serviceClient_GetAllKlientsCompleted(object sender, ToursServiceReference1.GetAllKlientsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            MyLongListSelectors.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }

    }
```

In case that I should provide more information please let me know. Hope not to receive down-votes as this is quiet low-quality question.

There is no sign of error or anything similar.

Thank you everyone for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect to see exactly?

You are doing nothing inside `serviceClient_GetAllKlientsCompleted` method. Your list will always be empty as you are not providing it any data to display

```
private void serviceClient_GetAllKlientsCompleted(object sender, ToursServiceReference1.GetAllKlientsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                //set the data context of list here 
            }

        }
```

Comment: May I ask how can I bind it to longlistselector? As I thought it could be something like this: LongListSelector.ItemsSource = e.Result;

Comment: `LongListSelector.DataContext = e.Result` or even `ItemsSource` will work

Comment: This says: An object refrence is required for the non-static field,method,property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.DataContext.get' How can I solve this?